# Canonical divisor of product of varieties

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ and $Y$ be a projective varieties with the canonical divisors $K_X$ and $K_Y$ respectively. Is it true that the canonical divisor of $X\times Y$ equals $p^*K_X+q^*K_Y$? Here $p:X\times Y\to X$, $q:X\times Y\to Y$ are the projection maps.

Comment: Sure. Do you know how to write the tangent bundle of $X \times Y$ in terms of the tangent bundles of $X$ and $Y$?